# Bizarre border behavior on tables with a fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm encountering the strangest thing. I'm using a simple jquery script to make a thead stay in place while the tbody scrolls. It works really well, except for some strange behavior with the border. Check out the Pen, and you can see the red border at the bottom of each th. I've tried putting it on the thead and the tr of the thead but it always behaves the same. It disappears under... itself? I'm not even sure.

http://codepen.io/sinrise/pen/NrxgWG

I'm using bootstrap and SCSS.

My solution for now is to add a :before to the ths that is just an abs pos box the height of the width of the border I want. It works fine but I'd really like to use an actual border, if possible. Thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-fixedheader" style="height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>One</th>
          <th>Two</th>
          <th>Three</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" value="#1" /></td>
          <td>Thing</td>
          <td>This is a long desctiption of some thing.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>#2</td>
          <td>Thing</td>
          <td>This is a long desctiption of some thing.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>#3</td>
          <td>Thing</td>
          <td>This is a long desctiption of some thing.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>#4</td>
          <td>Thing</td>
          <td>This is a long desctiption of some thing.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>#5</td>
          <td>Thing</td>
          <td>This is a long desctiption of some thing.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>#6</td>
          <td>Thing</td>
          <td>This is a long desctiption of some thing.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>#7</td>
          <td>Thing</td>
          <td>This is a long desctiption of some thing.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>#8</td>
          <td>Thing</td>
          <td>This is a long desctiption of some thing.</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container { padding: 30px; }

.table-fixedheader table thead tr th {
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.table-fixedheader thead {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

JQ

```
$(".table-fixedheader").scroll(function() {
  $(this).find("thead").css("transform", "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)");
});
```

Comment: Hi so you want the red border to stay put? In Firefox I can only see one at the top, and it scrolls out of view.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, it's on the thead cells so it should stay put with the rest of the thead and its descendants... I don't get it.

Comment: I see the problem, it's set to stay put but moves. Let me think a little more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far there are no solutions that don't involve changing the layout of the table with a fixed or absolutely positioned thead. The best solution is my own, but it involves not actually using a border. I just add:

```
&:before {
  border: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; bottom: -2px;
  width: 100%; height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

to the th of the thead and that works quite well. I suppose this is as good as it gets. The JS is minimal and otherwise reliable, and won't break the functionality of other scripts acting on tables, or mess with my layout. I hope this helps someone else, too! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the translate property. Try to fix the thead using position property. Here is your codepen for answer:

```
 $(".table-fixedheader").scroll(function() {
$(this).find("thead").css({'position':'absolute', 'width': $('.table').width() });      
    });
```

http://codepen.io/SESN/pen/BzKepx

Comment: Thanks but that breaks the layout. The solution I came up with keeps the table's structure intact. I'm just trying to get away with using a border instead of an absolutely positioned :before element.